# Adding values in array that has been passed through a method?

Tags: java

```
private void setAverage(int[] grades1) {

    for(int i = 0; i <= grades1.length; i++){
        avg += grades1[i];
    }

    System.out.println(avg);     
}
```

for some reason I get an error for this code saying:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
   at StudentRecords.setAverage(StudentRecords.java:29)
   at StudentRecords.<init>(StudentRecords.java:16)
   at StudentRecordTest.main(StudentRecordTest.java:54)
```

Comment: Read the doc of this exception

Comment: The termination statement should use less than, not less than or equal to.

Comment: Why is there a downvote on this question?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `<` instead of `<=`. In your code, if `grades1` has a size of 10, you will try to get `grades1[10]` at the end of your loop, whereas you can only get from 0 to 9.

```
private void setAverage(int[] grades1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < grades1.length; i++){
        avg += grades1[i];
    }
    System.out.println(avg);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setAverage(int[] grades1) {

for(int i = 0; i < grades1.length; i++){
    avg += grades1[i];
}

System.out.println(avg);     
}
```

E.g. you have an array of length 3 then you have indexes 0,1,2.
You must not try to get index 3

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` because your code is trying to access the `grades1[3]` element in the array which does not exist. Let's take a closer look:

The length of your array is `3`. This means your array starts at `index 0` and ends at `index 2`------->`[0, 2]`. If you count the numbers `0, 1, 2,` you get `3` which is the length.

Now, the logic is off in your for loop. You are starting at `i = 0` and ending at `i <= 3`. When you are accessing `grades1[i]` in your for loop, you access each element `i` until the condition is false.

```
// iteration 1
for(int i = 0; i <= grades1.length; i++){
        avg += grades1[i];// accesses grades1[0]
    }
-------------------------------------------------
// iteration 2
for(int i = 0; i <= grades1.length; i++){
        avg += grades1[i];// accesses grades1[1]
    }
-------------------------------------------------
// iteration 3
for(int i = 0; i <= grades1.length; i++){
        avg += grades1[i];// accesses grades1[2]
    }
-------------------------------------------------
// iteration 4
for(int i = 0; i <= grades1.length; i++){
        avg += grades1[i];// tries to access grades1[3] which does not exist
    }
-------------------------------------------------
```

There are a couple of ways to fix this:

```
1. for (int i = 0; i < grades1.length; i++)

2. for (int i = 0; i <= grades1.length - 1; i++)
```

Hope this helps :-)